# How to resolved this error "Cannot invoke getObejectAtPath with argument list type of string"

Tags: ios, swift, restkit

I am configuring restkit but i'm getting error like

> "cannot invoke getObjectAtPath" with argument list.....

so how to solve this problem and i also want to write function globally.

```
func fatchingData() {
        var queryParams = ""
        var path = "property_type/"
        RKObjectManager.sharedManager().getObjectsAtPath(path, parameters: queryParams, success: { operation, mappingResult in

            self.resultData = mappingResult.array()


            },
            failure:{ operation, error in
                println("error")
            }
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with `queryParams`. You declared it as a `String` but it must be `Dictionary`.

Here is sample code for it:

```
func loadVenues() {
    let latLon = "37.33,-122.03" // approximate latLon of The Mothership (a.k.a Apple headquarters)
    let queryParams = [
        "ll": latLon,
        "client_id": kCLIENTID,
        "client_secret": kCLIENTSECRET,
        "categoryId": "4bf58dd8d48988d1e0931735",
        "v" : "20140617"
    ]

    RKObjectManager.sharedManager().getObjectsAtPath("/v2/venues/search", parameters: queryParams,
        success:{ operation, mappingResult in
            self.venues = mappingResult.array()
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        },
        failure:{ operation, error in
            NSLog("What do you mean by 'there is no coffee?': \(error!.localizedDescription)")
        }
    )
}
```

Reference from [HERE](http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=11245&start=20).

Hope it helps.